# download a complete branch from svn

Tags: svn

I want download( [cilk branch of gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/cilkplus-4_7-branch/)) to build it with my gcc-4.7. Is there any easy way to download it using svn??

Comment: This question shows no research effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
svn co http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/cilkplus-4_7-branch/
```

Comment: where did u get this from. Can you suggest a good tutorial I have been searching many tutorials but did not get this command

Comment: I got this from my head.  "co" is short for "checkout" which means "go download the current version of the code in the SVN repository at the given URL."

Comment: Branches in SVN are synonymous with sub directories.  That means if you check out http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc you will get all branches of development, including the main trunk, all snapshots, and all active branches.  If you check out (by convention it's this way, it is not a requirement) http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches you likely get all non-trunk branches of development, and if you check out http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/cilkplus-4_7-branch/ you likely get just the cilkplus-4_7-branch.